# visibility of friend functions when creating functors

Tags: c++, scope, visibility, friend, functor

See the code below. The `drive()` **is in the scope**, I can `drive` the `porsche`. However, unless I uncomment the declaration of `drive()`, g++ gives a very weird ‘drive’ was not declared in this scope error when trying to create the functor. Why?

```
#include <functional>

class car {
    friend void drive(const car c);
};

//void drive(const car c);

int main() {

    car porsche;
    drive(porsche);
    std::pointer_to_unary_function<car, void> functor(drive);

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 1:** I am almost satified with the answer concerning ADL, however I did tell the type of the argument of drive, it is the first template parameter, it is car:

```
std::pointer_to_unary_function<car, void> functor(drive);
```

**UPDATE 2:** OK, here is an even simpler code, we do not need the functor and the functional header:

```
class car {
    friend void drive(const car c);
};

//void drive(const car c) { }

int main() {
    car porsche;
    drive(porsche);
    void (*f)(const car);
    f = drive;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I understand why the compiler cannot find `drive` with ADL. The reason is the same as above, but this code is not obscured by the template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit template instantiation: weird "f was not declared in this scope"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775581/explicit-template-instantiation-weird-f-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Comment: ADL is not about deducing argument types, it is about looking up names.  Charles' answer appears correct.

Comment: Yes, I am about to delete that question. The code here is much better.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: I did not say Charles' answer was wrong, I just do not get it. :"(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare a `friend` function with an unqualified id in a class and that function is not a member of another class, it names a function in the nearest enclosing non-class, non-function prototype scope.

If that function hasn't previously been declared then the `friend` declaration doesn't make that function visible in that scope.

However, that function is visible for *argument dependent lookup*.

In the expression `drive(porsche);`, the `porsche` has type `car` so ADL is used and the friend function can be found.

In the expression `drive` there are no arguments so ADL is not performed. There is no declaration of `drive` visible so the lookup fails.

Comment: @Ali: Why do you think the compiler can find `drive`? If it's not doing ADL for `drive` (which it isn't because it's not a function call expression) there is no visible declaration for `drive`.

Comment: OK, I will read more on what ADL is. I would think from your answer that deducing the argument type suffices.

Comment: @Ali: I don't understand your point. You specify all the arguments to the template, there's not argument deduction needed or possible. The problem is that the name `drive` is not visible in any non-ADL lookup.

Comment: Please give me some time to read what ADL exactly is. From your answer it seems to me that deducing the type should suffice. Thanks for your answer and for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

Because friend doesn't declare a function and you're trying to call a global function which doesn't exist.

Comment: If it does not declare a function then how can I drive the porsche?

Comment: If you want to have drive as a global function (even though usually what people do is class member functions), then you just need to define the drive function. One way to define it would be: class car { friend void drive(const car c) {write something here;}}; And another way to define it would be on the global level: void drive(const car c) {write something here;}. The friend void drive(const car c); itself doesn't define a function. It barely says that if a function like that exists, it's a friend of that class.

Comment: Friend *does* declare a function.